# setlocale() returns 'C' when running as root

Tags: c++, macos, locale

I'm using the following to get the system locale:

```
currentLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
```

This works great normally, I get (for example) `en_GB.UTF-8`.

However, when running the same program as root, I get `C`. How can I get the system locale when running as root?

Comment: Are you just running as a real root, or is this some part of some `sudo` invocation? It makes perfect sense for the OS not to elevate user's environment variables into a privileged context.

Comment: Real root, it works fine with sudo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "system locale." Each user can set the locale by itself and it may differ for each program (e.g. execute LC_ALL="en_US" locale). A return value of `C` means that the user has not set any locale and the default locale is active.